# Using ldapRegistry properties in Java running on Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have some Java code running on Liberty Profile which authenticates with MS Active Directory and makes LDAP searches. The code use JNDI and does what it is intended to do. The problem is that the LDAP parameters are hard coded in Java. Works, but could be improved:

```
ldap.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://ad.foo.bar:389");
ldap.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=account,OU=A,DC=ad,DC=foo,DC=bar");
ldap.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "apoorlykeptsecret");
...
ldapCtxt = new InitialDirContext(ldap);
```

Is it possible to pick the LDAP properties up from an ldapRegistry element in the server.xml file instead? Or am I on the wrong track? Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to configure that using the `<ldapRegistry>` element in server.xml.

For example:

```
<ldapRegistry id="ldap" realm="SampleLdapADRealm" 
    host="ldapserver.mycity.mycompany.com" port="389"
    baseDN="cn=users,dc=adtest,dc=mycity,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
    bindDN="cn=testuser,cn=users,dc=adtest,dc=mycity,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
    bindPassword="testuserpwd"
    ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory"> 
  <activedFilters
    userFilter="(&(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectcategory=user))"
    groupFilter="(&(cn=%v)(objectcategory=group))" 
    userIdMap="user:sAMAccountName" 
    groupIdMap="*:cn" 
    groupMemberIdMap="memberOf:member" >
  </activedFilters>
</ldapRegistry>
```

For full doc see: [Configuring LDAP user registries in Liberty](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ldap.html)

As an alternative quick approach, you could put those values in your server.xml configuration as JNDI entries and obtain the values in your application by JNDI lookup.  For example:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="ldap/provider_url" value="ldap://ad.foo.bar:389"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ldap/secuirty_principal" value="CN=account,OU=A,DC=ad,DC=foo,DC=bar"/>
<!-- WARNING: Storing passwords is JNDI is not secure -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ldap/security_credentials" value="apoorlykeptsecret"/>


String providerUrl = InitialContext.doLookup("ldap/provider_url");
// etc...
```

Comment: The question is to know if there is a way to get ldapRegistry details as jndi look up. Alternative approach is good but is there a way to directly get ldapRegistry as jndi look up. Just like data source.

Comment: Nope, it is not possible to look up an ldapRegistry via JNDI